# Custom module in magento not show grid

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I create a custom module in magento admin. The problem is **grid.php** extend from **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid** not display grid (only show the buttons and header text).
The content of grid.php:

```
class Ha_Hvdmodule_Block_Adminhtml_Information_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid{
public function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('informationGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

protected  function _prepareCollection(){
    $collection = Mage::getModel('hvdmodule/information')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns(){
    $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('hvdmodule')->__('ID'),
        'align' => 'right',
        'width' => '10px',
        'index' => 'id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('hvdmodule')->__('Name'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'width' => '15px',
        'index' => 'name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('content', array(
       'header' => Mage::helper('hvdmodule')->__('Content'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'width' => '20px',
        'index' => 'content',
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
}


?>
```

the content layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout>
 <hvdmodule_adminhtml_information_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="hvdmodule/adminhtml_information" name="information"/>
    </reference>
</hvdmodule_adminhtml_information_index>
</layout>
```

the content controller:

```
class Ha_Hvdmodule_Adminhtml_InformationController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

public function indexAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

}

Comment: Did you grid.php is called or not ? try to print the collection.

Comment: print collection? i don't understand

Comment: just echo something in grid.php if it shows than you can print the collection by var_dump($collection); check this.

Comment: i tried var_dump($collection) and show "bool(false)", it's problem?

Comment: did you try to show something on the grid.php to check the page is running or not ?

Comment: yes, i want to show the grid with colunms added, but it only show the buttons and header text, not show colunms

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31596/discussion-between-mahmood-rehman-and-skidrow)

Answer (score 0):

Have you got Information block setup as container?

```
class Ha_Hvdmodule_Block_Adminhtml_Information extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container 
{
    public function __construct()
    {        
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_information';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'information';

        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('module')->__('title');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('module')->__('Add Item');

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```